# How to get path Json in nested Pentaho?

Tags: json, input, pentaho, jsonpath

I´m importing a json file that has the following structure (see code) in Pentaho. I have been able to obtain the first data but those that are nested do not know how to obtain it.

I know get label display and isMeasure but i don´t know how to get the next nested, label, display and display_sequence

```
Name     Path
label    $.dimension.*..label
display  $.dimension.*..display
Measure  $.dimension.*..isMeasure
Code     $.dimension.*..code
label2   $.dimension.*..code.label ???

{
"copyright": "(c) World Health Organization",
"dataset":
[
],
"attribute":
[
],
"dimension":
[
{
"label": "BLABLA",
"display": "BLELE",
"isMeasure": false,
"code":
[
{
"label": "AAAA",
"display": "CCCCC",
"display_sequence": 10,
"url": "",
"attr":
[
]
},
{
"label": "BBBB",
"display": "DDDD",
"display_sequence": 20,
"url": "",
"attr":
[
]
}
]
}
],
"fact":
[
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to get first `"label": "BLABLA"` path should be `$.dimension.*.label` this will get only label `BLABLA`

for display and measure use below path

`$.dimension.*.display`
`$.dimension.*.isMeasure`

now get to another two label which is on code array the path should be `$.dimension.*.code.*.label` this will give you only code array label.

for display and display_sequence use below path

`$.dimension.*.code.*.display`
`$.dimension.*.code.*.display_sequence`